# What does "equilibrium under its own gravity" mean for a body of fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, pressure, astrophysics, equilibrium

> A spherical body of radius $R$ consists of a fluid of constant density and is in equilibrium under its own gravity. If $P(r)$ is the pressure at $r(r < R)$, then the correct option(s) is(are)?

That is the wording of the question. 
**My question is what exactly do they mean by equilibrium under it's own gravity?**

Comment: I take it to mean something like a planet made of fluid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually the starting model for a [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_structure), which at some point is basically a sphere of gas supported by pressure. Indeed, if you ignore any contribution from radiation, and $P(r)$ is the pressure at radius $r$, then the weight of a shell of the star is balanced by $P$ such that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}P}{{\rm d}r} = -\frac{GM(<r)\rho}{r^2}
$$

which is just an statement that the star is in [hydrostatic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium)